# Can I create a .MP4 container with Qt APIs?

Tags: qt, mp4, qtmultimedia

Is it possible to create a `.mp4` container with **Qt Multimedia** or some other Qt *API*s ?

I understand that Qt does not have encoding APIs, **BUT** if I've a **library** helping me to encode & decode, then **can I use Qt to create the MP4 container** and the additional third party library to encode video data into it ?

Comment: why down-voted ? did I do a mistake in the format or scope of this question ?

Comment: I'm *not* the downvoter but... your question is extremely vague.  You ask "can I rely on Qt to create the MP4 container?".  What are you doing that would cause Qt to create a container?  Please show some code that illustrates what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: all I wanted to know :- **Is there an API is Qt to create a `.mp4` file with the required video-audio format?** thats it. the answer can be No as well. but I need to know if there is a way to do it using Qt. anyways, no I guess. otherwise there would answers proposing the solution

Comment: No. You cannot. Even if there is an API. Maybe in 3 years. This area of functionality is so fubar now in Qt, you cannot rely on it. Try QtGStreamer or so.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Is *QtGStreamer* available with Qt 5.9.1 that is on mobile ? I am using commercial version of Qt that is 5.9.1 on iOS & Android primarily

Comment: QtGStreamer is an open source and not part of Qt. Just some popular library to enable multimedia for Qt with GStreamer. At least you would be able to control the pipeline. IMHO the easiest way to go. But mind that GStreamer itself may surprise you from time to time. That is Linux.

Comment: thanks for the information. thats all is the information I needed for this question. if you post an answer with this information replying negative to my question that Qt does not support creating the container then, it will also be helpful for some other programmers asking the same question & wondering about it. I will be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: still negative voting on the question :( I will edit it to make it clear

Comment: I upvoted it. Have fun with QtGStreamer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt (version 5.9.2 or earlier) does not have support for creating or writing to .mp4 files.

You might be able to do this with a third party add-on [QtGstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html)